# Hide/Remove Pay with a debit or credit card

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

Is there a way of hiding the option "Pay with a debit or credit card"? I would like my users to only pay with paypal accounts.

I have checked many options in the sandbox dev area and cant find such an option?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The option is called "PayPal Account Optional" and can be found under https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/customerprofileweb?cmd=_profile-website-payments (use www.sandbox.paypal.com for sandbox accounts) - this will allow you to choose if the "guest payment" option will be available or not during checkout.

Note that that a buyer will still have the option to create a PayPal account if he does not have one.

In Express Checkout, you may also pass `SOLUTIONTYPE=MARK` to achieve the same.

Comment: Not working at all